# How to create, name, and populate new column with output Using For loop R

Tags: r, dataframe, for-loop

I'm trying to write a loop that takes variables from some columns and calculates using a formula, then populate results in different columns with similar column names with a suffix.

I have a dataframe with 100000 rows 53 columns; 3-29 cols will be used for calculation ..

So far what I did ...

```
GC05cr_h16_dat2$ln1 <- 0

for(i in 3:29) {      
  log_read <- log(GC05cr_h16_dat2[ , i] +1) /max(GC05cr_h16_dat2[ , i])
  GC05cr_h16_dat2$ln1[i] <- log_read
}
```

The table:

```
  head(GC05cr_h16_dat2)
    # A tibble: 6 × 54
        chr     start EE87893 EE87894 EE87895 EE87896 EE87897 EE87898 EE87899 EE87900 EE87901 EE87902 EE87903
          <chr>   <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>
        1 chr3   1.45e8       4       2       4       2       4       2       5       5       4       1       4
        2 chr4   1.63e8       2       4       3       1       1       4       5       5       5       4       5
        3 chr4   3.57e7       3       5       3       1       6       6       5      10       4       6       3
        4 chr18  6.58e7       2       1       6       6       2       1       3       5       3       4       1
        5 chr10  8.43e7       5       1       4       3       1       5       0      11       2       4       8
        6 chr3   1.84e8       5       1       3       5       5       4       3       9       4       3       6
        #
```

The results of all columns under consideration of `for` loop are printed in a single column under column name `ln1`.

My expected results of any single column would be printed in a separate column and the name of the column would be suffixed by `ln1`.

```
EE87893ln1 EE87894ln1 EE87895ln1 .....
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using your existing code, you can tweak it to change your `for` loop index from an integer to the column names of interest, then directly create a new column using `paste0`:

```
for (i in names(GC05cr_h16_dat2)[grep("EE", names(GC05cr_h16_dat2))]){
  GC05cr_h16_dat2[, paste0(i, "ln1")] <- log(GC05cr_h16_dat2[ , i] + 1) / max(GC05cr_h16_dat2[ , i])
}
```

Output (you may need to scroll over because the output is wide):

```
    chr    start EE87893 EE87894 EE87895 EE87896 EE87897 EE87898 EE87899 EE87900 EE87901 EE87902 EE87903 EE87893ln1 EE87894ln1 EE87895ln1 EE87896ln1 EE87897ln1 EE87898ln1 EE87899ln1 EE87900ln1 EE87901ln1 EE87902ln1 EE87903ln1
1  chr3 1.45e+08       4       2       4       2       4       2       5       5       4       1       4  0.3218876  0.2197225  0.2682397  0.1831020  0.2682397  0.1831020  0.3583519  0.1628872  0.3218876  0.1155245  0.2011797
2  chr4 1.63e+08       2       4       3       1       1       4       5       5       5       4       5  0.2197225  0.3218876  0.2310491  0.1155245  0.1155245  0.2682397  0.3583519  0.1628872  0.3583519  0.2682397  0.2239699
3  chr4 3.57e+07       3       5       3       1       6       6       5      10       4       6       3  0.2772589  0.3583519  0.2310491  0.1155245  0.3243184  0.3243184  0.3583519  0.2179905  0.3218876  0.3243184  0.1732868
4 chr18 6.58e+07       2       1       6       6       2       1       3       5       3       4       1  0.2197225  0.1386294  0.3243184  0.3243184  0.1831020  0.1155245  0.2772589  0.1628872  0.2772589  0.2682397  0.0866434
5 chr10 8.43e+07       5       1       4       3       1       5       0      11       2       4       8  0.3583519  0.1386294  0.2682397  0.2310491  0.1155245  0.2986266  0.0000000  0.2259006  0.2197225  0.2682397  0.2746531
6  chr3 1.84e+08       5       1       3       5       5       4       3       9       4       3       6  0.3583519  0.1386294  0.2310491  0.2986266  0.2986266  0.2682397  0.2772589  0.2093259  0.3218876  0.2310491  0.2432388
```

If you wanted to specify the columns by numbers directly (ie, columns 3 though 29), just use:

```
for (i in names(GC05cr_h16_dat2)[3:29]){...}
```

You could also use `lapply` for this:

```
GC05cr_h16_dat2[paste0(names(GC05cr_h16_dat2)[3:13], "ln1")] <- 
  lapply(GC05cr_h16_dat2[3:13], function(x) log(x + 1) / max(x))
```